# Business Rules Implementation: So I had set of inputs and based on that input set need an outcome

Tags: python, redis

Need suggestions like I had set of input parameters and on the basis of their combination need some business level outcome like do this.

I had some thought for implementing same but It doesn't seems highly optimized in terms of performance.

Problem Set:

```
Input Parameters: Activity, Client, Supplier, Flow, Product Type, Category

Sample Rule: Key - QC:Client12:Flow1
             Value- [{
                    'instructions': ['QCACCINS001', 'QCACCINS002'],
                    'mandatory_fields': ['ATR001', 'ATR002'],
                    'expression': 'ATR0001>15000'
                    'success': 'do some action',
                    'failure': 'do some action'}]
```

I am planning to put the structure in redis as key-value pair and get rule definition every time we required with set of input parameter.

Problem in the above mentioned solution is combinations like One parameter Activity is fixed and rest of all it can be or not.

Please suggest.